# How to order by max(a,b) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-function

Consider the following table:

```
 id    a    b
--------------
 1     5    1
 2     2    3
 3     4    2
 4     3    6
 5     0    1
 6     2    2
```

I would like to order it by `max(a,b)` in descending order, so that the result will be:

```
 id    a    b
--------------
 4     3    6
 1     5    1
 3     4    2
 2     2    3
 6     2    2
 5     0    1
```

What will be the SQL query to perform such ordering ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use GREATEST :

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY GREATEST(a, b) DESC
```

Comment: Beware that both values must be not null. Example: select greatest(null,3) returns null. In that case you would have to use coalesce. select greatest(coalesce(null,0),coalesce(null,0)) this returns 0.

Comment: @nick rulez: ah! mysql... you wonder why one would use it when it is so irrational. Thanks for mentioning it though, +1

Comment: @Vincent: you're right. I don't understand the reason of this strange behaviour. :)

Comment: @nick rulez: Thank for the `COALESCE` extension. In my case it is indeed needed because the rows in the table are a result of `LEFT JOIN`. By the way, is there any difference between `COALESCE` and `IFNULL` in MySQL ?

Comment: `COALESCE` can deals with multiple values, whereas `IFNULL` deals with only two values